# Why scrolling background hiding the game object when i touch on screen the game object hide behind the scrolling object in unity.

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**Scene**

I have a scrolling background and a sphere but when i play the game and try to move the sphere on touch(android) it moves perfectly but it is hiding behind the background.I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: probably the code that repositions the sphere, places it behind the background. can share that code and say where you background is positioned and in which axis? please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If this is a 2d project, you might want to have your background and sphere in different layers. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html